# What sort of index type should I be using

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, indexing

I have a table with a varchar(6), datetime, and two floats.  It has over 30 million records

The varchar and datetime are used as a join condition on a table with over 500k records, and the sum and average of the two floats used in the results.

I'm after index advice to speed things up.

There are 112 unique varchar values, and 525k unique datetime values.

The join condition is `WHERE varchar = varchar AND datetime BETWEEN Date1 AND Date2`

I've been playing with various combinations of clustered, nonclustered, composite, and covering indexes, but I'm not really an expert on this, so I'd appreciate peoples opinion.

My main questions are around is a clustered or nonclustered index preferred here, and why?  Is a covering index better, why?

I'm seeing various changes to the execution path as I change things, but I have no clue if a Eager Index Spool with a nested loop is better than a hash match.

Cheers for any help.

Comment: It depends, but a clustered index on the datatime column might do the job - look at execution times and io first, not the execution plan...

Comment: Just the datetime column?  I was under the impression that since i'm querying on both the datetime and the varchar I'd need both in my index

Comment: The clustered index should be one which has an inherent order. Inserts will happen at the end of your table It's best if this will no fragment your index, If there is a clustered index it includes all columns implicitly. It will serve as lookup index for all other indexes. So: define a clustered index with an inherent order and afterwards the varchar index. And have a look on table's size...

Comment: @Matt: yes, the `datetime` column alone as the clustering index might speed things up significantly. The `datetime` seems to be quite selective - while the `Varchar` column only has 100 distinct values over 30 million rows, so each value will be appearing a whole lot of times --> not very selective. Also, `varchar` is usually not a good match for a clustering index, since it's by default variable length, and often fairly long (`varchar(50)` or `varchar(100)`) and thus makes a lousy candidate for a clustering index.

Comment: One more point: if possible you  could transfer your 112 varchar values into a look up table and bind them as a reference. This will decrease size and speed up performance as well...

Comment: A clustered index has the benefit of not using additional disk space.  Did you try a composite clustered on varchar, datetime?  And if that is a key then make it the PK.  A PK can be used by the query optimizer to know it can stop looking.